# Query to find number of employees by month

Tags: postgresql

I want to find number of employees for every month in date range - Jan 2012 to Jan 2013.

Example history:

- We have 500 employees hired before 2012
- January 2012 - 30 employees were hired
- February - 20 employees left company
  -March - nothing changed

I want result like,

```
Jan 2012   530
Feb 2012   510
March 2012 550
...
```

In `employees` table I have columns:

```
id
employee_name
date_started
date_terminated
employee_status_type /* true for current employees, false otherwise */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table employees (id int, date_started date, date_terminated date);

insert into employees values
  (1,'2012-01-01','2012-07-01'),
  (2,'2012-11-01',NULL),
  (3,'2010-01-01','2012-02-10');

with

time_space as (
  select
    gs::date as bom,
    (gs + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date as eom
  from
     generate_series('2012-01-01'::date,'2013-01-01'::date, '1 month') gs

)

select
  ts.bom,
  coalesce(x.employees,0) as employees
from
  time_space ts
  left join (
    select
      bom,
      count(*) as employees
    from
      time_space ts
      join employees e on (coalesce(e.date_terminated,'3000-01-01'::date) >= ts.bom and e.date_started <= ts.eom)
    group by
      bom) x using (bom)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/82fc7/1)